# Swift custom table cell

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to use Custom Table cell in my swift app, and faced a problem: My application crashes when I run my app.

My custom table cell class is SimpleTableCell (Objective-C class)

and my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method (swift) is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SimpleTableItem", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let data = TableData[indexPath.row]


        cell.textLabel?.text = data.description



        if (data.image == nil)
        {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:"image.jpg")
            load_image(image_base_url + data.imageurl!, imageview: cell.imageView!, index: indexPath.row)
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imageView?.image = TableData[indexPath.row].image
        }

        return cell

    }
```

My app crashes with the error:
unable to dequeue a cell with identifier SimpleTableItem - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

What does it mean?

Comment: The runtime is asking you what "SimpleTableItem" is. You have no such cell in the storyboard, and you have not associated it with any nib, so where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: Did you register it in your viewDidLoad? Something like: `tableView.registerClass(SimpleTableItem.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(SimpleTableItem))`

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, select your tableView cell and in the attributes inspector, set the identifier to "SimpleTableItem". Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is trying to find a cell with the identifier `"SimpleTableItem"`, but it seems that you haven't given a cell that identifier anywhere. One way to do this is to choose a cell in the Table View in Storyboard, go to the Attributes Inspector and set its identifier to `SimpleTableItem`.